# How can I automate testing of a non-automation enabled desktop application

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, appium, desktop-application

How can I automate testing of a non-automation enabled desktop application using Appium, WinAppDriver, Visual Studio, and C#? The application is not showing any XPath or other identifying elements. Are there any techniques or methods that I can use to enable automation support for the application and allow me to perform automation testing?

I am using Appium version 1.17, WinAppDriver version 0.7, Visual Studio 2019 and C# to try to automate testing of a custom built non-automation enabled desktop application. The application is a accounting software with custom functionality.
I have tried to locate identifying elements or XPath of the application by using inspect.exe but it did not find any xpath or identifying elements. I also tried to enable the automation support but it was not successful and the application was not responding.
I am getting the error "element not found" when trying to interact with the application using Appium and WinAppDriver.
Any suggestions to automate this application using the above mentioned tools would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use appium inspector that you can find going to this link.
https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector
You will need appium server running to get this working.